# How to test a react native component whose UI changes based on async call in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I have a react native component `OrdersScreen` which I am not able to test   because the component gets updated when setState : `setRenderLoader(false)` is called in React.useEffect() hook.

```
  const OrdersScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  let [renderLoader, setRenderLoader] = React.useState(true);
  let [ordersInfo, setOrdersInfo] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ordersController.getOrdersForAgent() // some API call
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("getOrdersForAgent res", res);
        setOrdersInfo(res);
        if (res)
          res.forEach(ord => dispatch(addOrder(ord)));
        setRenderLoader(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("getOrdersForAgent err", err);
      });
  }, []);
return (
    <View
      style={ordersScreenStyle.container}>
      {renderLoader
        ?
        (<Loader />)
        :
        (<SectionList
          ...
        />)}
    </View>
```

Below is the test code I have:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {act} from 'react-test-renderer'

describe('<OrdersScreen/>', () => {
    test('Verify order item', async () => {
        const ORDER_ITEMS = DEFAULT_VALUE;
        ordersController.getOrdersForAgent = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(ORDER_ITEMS));
        const setRenderLoader = jest.fn();

        let component;
        await act(async () => {
            //render with redux just wraps renderer.create(component) with a redux store
            component = await renderWithRedux(<OrdersScreen />);
        })
        const root = component.root;
        let tree = component.toJSON();
        console.log('tree', tree);
        if (store.getState().ordersReducer.length === 0) {
            expect(setRenderLoader).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        }
        else {
            expect(setRenderLoader).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
        }



    })
})
```

I get the below error:

```
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      142 |         if (res)
      143 |           res.forEach(ord => dispatch(addOrder(ord)));
    > 144 |         setRenderLoader(false);
```

Could anyone please give pointers as to how this component is to be tested? I am quite new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `dispatch(addOrder(ord))` is `async` then you want to handle those actions inside a `for..of` loop instead of `forEach`.

> The `forEach` loop acts differently than the `for` loop, while the for loop `await` the iteration before moving further, the `forEach` loop executes all of the iterations simultaneously.

```js
for (const ord of res){
 dispatch(addOrder(ord))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    let [renderLoader, setRenderLoader] = React.useState(true);
  let [ordersInfo, setOrdersInfo] = React.useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    ordersController?.getOrdersForAgent() // some API call
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("getOrdersForAgent res", res);
        setOrdersInfo(res);
        if (res)
          res?.forEach(ord => dispatch(addOrder(ord)));
        setRenderLoader(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("getOrdersForAgent err", err);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src="/logo.svg" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.jsx</code> and save to reload! :)
        </p>
        <span className="App-link">Hello from codedamn :)</span>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Try with this code here i am only getting ordersController not imported error